# How do Pokemon Mega Evolve by themselves?

Tags: pokemon

According to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mega_Evolution):

> In order to Mega Evolve, most Pokemon must be holding their
>   appropriate Mega Stone and the Trainer must have a Key Stone. Only
>   Rayquaza does not need a Mega Stone to Mega Evolve; instead, it must
>   know the move Dragon Ascent.

In the Pokemon XY anime, at the end of the first thirty or so episodes there is a short clip introducing all the of mega evolutions. Most of them are seen to be wild and mega evolve as they feel.

If they had a trainer but the anime didn't show it, fair enough. However, what about Mewtwo Y in the 16th movie, and Latias and Latios in the 18th movie, they definitely did not have trainers.

So how do they Mega Evolve by themselves?

Comment: Actually, I dont even remember seeing mewtwo's stone(any of them) during the movie it(she?) megaevolves.